# Pinchas not jealous and not killing the 24,000?

Tags: pinchas

Maybe I am missing something from the Pinchas story, it goes like this:

1. Thousands of the Hebrews sin with the non-Jewish women. Pinchas does nothing.
2. Moses orders to judge and kill them all. Pinchas does nothing.
3. Zimri comes to Moses, claims he wants to be with Kozbi. Pinchas argues with Moses but does nothing.
4. Zimri goes back to his camp and does the thing and Pinchas comes to kill them.

Where was he when the thousands sinned?

Can one claim he's a zealot after overlooking thousands of cases?

Comment: Where do you see that the others did it in public? That's needed for kanoim poigem boy

Comment: Rank and file Bnai Yisrael commiting a sin do not carry the same weight as a nasi and leader doing so

Comment: @Orangesandlemons isn't it a Machlokes?